# Swift Protocols with Associated Type Requirement and Default Implementation

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have been struggling very hard with Swift Protocols and Associated Types for a long time. I started again with basic to really understand what is going wrong and I followed this [article](http://robnapier.net/erasure) of TypeErasure in Swift Protocols with Associated Type Requirement by Rob Napier but still i have no luck.

Find the code below

```
// An Animal can eat
protocol Animal {
    associatedtype Food
    func feed(food: Food) -> Void
}

struct AnyAnimal<Food>: Animal {
    private let _feed: (Food) -> Void
    init<Base: Animal where Food == Base.Food>(_ base: Base) {
        _feed = base.feed
    }
    func feed(food: Food) { _feed(food) }
}

// Kinds of Food
struct Grass {}

struct Cow: Animal {
    func feed(food: Grass) { print("moo") }
}

struct Goat: Animal {
    func feed(food: Grass) { print("bah") }
}

let grassEaters = [AnyAnimal(Cow()), AnyAnimal(Goat())]
for animal in grassEaters {
    animal.feed(Grass())
}
```

Now i wanted to give a default implementation in the protocol Animal like below

```
extension Animal {

    func feed(food: Food) -> Void {
        print("unknown")
    }
}
```

And when i removed the function from the struct Cow i get the error message that Cow doesn't conform to Protocol Animal.

Does that mean you cannot have Type Erasures and Default Implementation together?. Is there any way where i can do TypeErasure and also keep a Default Implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to the type erasure and you'll get the same
error message if you remove the `struct AnyAnimal<Food>` definition.

If you remove the `feed()` method from `struct Cow` then 
the compiler cannot infer the associated type `Food`. So either you
use a concrete type in the default implementation:

```
extension Animal {
    func feed(food: Grass) -> Void {
        print("unknown")
    }
}

struct Cow: Animal {
}
```

or you define a type alias `Food` for each type using the
default implementation:

```
extension Animal {
    func feed(food: Food) -> Void {
        print("unknown")
    }
}

struct Cow: Animal {
    typealias Food = Grass
}
```

It is also possible to define a default type for `Food` in the
protocol:

```
protocol Animal {
    associatedtype Food = Grass
    func feed(food: Food) -> Void
}


extension Animal {
    func feed(food: Food) -> Void {
        print("unknown")
    }
}

struct Cow: Animal {
}
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't realise it was so silly question. Thank You!