# Error using Self in generic function where clause

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, swift-protocols

I am running into an issue when I try to use `Self` as part of a `where` clause in a generic function which is part of a protocol.

For example, say I have this protocol and this generic function defined:

```
protocol Animal {
    associatedtype FoodSource
    func eat(_ food:FoodSource)
}

// The where clause specifies that T2 must conform to
// whatever type is T1's FoodSource associated type 
func feed<T1: Animal, T2>(animal:T1, food:T2) where T2 == T1.FoodSource {
    animal.eat(food)
}
```

The function Feed uses the bracketed statement to declare that the first parameter must conform to the `Animal` protocol.  It uses the `where` clause to declare that the second parameter's type must conform to the associated type of the first parameter.

It's possible to create classes which conform to this generic function's requirements and everything works perfectly.  For example:

```
protocol Meat {}
protocol Vegetable {}

class Rabbit : Animal {
    typealias FoodSource = Vegetable
    func eat(_ food:FoodSource) {
        print("the Rabbit ate the \(type(of:food))")
    }
}

class Lion : Animal {
    typealias FoodSource = Meat
    func eat(_ food:FoodSource) {
        print("the Lion ate the \(type(of:food))")
    }
}

class Carrot : Vegetable {}
class Steak : Meat {}
class ChickenSalad : Meat, Vegetable {}

// works because Carrot conforms to Vegetable
// prints: "the Rabbit ate the Carrot"
feed(animal: Rabbit(), food: Carrot())

// works because Steak conforms to Meat
// prints: "the Lion ate the Steak"
feed(animal: Lion(), food: Steak())

// works because ChickenSalad conforms to Meat
// prints: "the Lion ate the ChickenSalad"
feed(animal: Lion(), food: ChickenSalad())

// works because ChickenSalad conforms to Vegetable
// prints: "the Rabbit ate the ChickenSalad"
feed(animal: Rabbit(), food: ChickenSalad())
```

So far so good.

However, when I implement the same pattern of generics as part of a protocol, it no longer works:

```
protocol Food {
    func feed<T:Animal>(to:T) where Self == T.FoodSource
}

extension Food {
    func feed<T:Animal>(to animal:T) where Self == T.FoodSource {
        animal.eat(self)
    }
}

class SteakSalad : Food, Meat, Vegetable {}

SteakSalad().feed(to: Lion())
```

When executed, this block throws the following error:

```
error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
SteakSalad().feed(to: Lion())
             ^
```

Is there some way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810270/swift-protocols-with-associated-type-requirement-and-default-implementation

Comment: Maybe I'm thick but I'm not sure exactly how this applies to my case.  I know the examples provided are quite similar in terms of content, but it seems like a separate issue.  In the case of the linked post, type inference no longer works on `Cow` because the associated type for `Cow.Food` can't be determined without that method signature.  In the case of my example, I don't understand why the type wouldn't be inferred directly from the provided parameter (in this case `Lion`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Before discussing this, I highly advice you to rethink your problem and simplify your types. Once you wander down the road of mixing generics and protocols in Swift, you will be fighting the type system nonstop. Part of this is that complex types are complex and it is difficult to get them correct even with a very strong type system. Part of it is that Swift does not have a very strong type system. Compared to Objective-C or Ruby, sure, it's incredibly powerful, but it's still fairly weak around generic types and there are many concepts you can't express (there are no higher-kinded types, there is no way to express covariance or contravariance, no dependent types, and there are weird quirks like protocols don't always conform to themselves). In nearly every case where I've worked with a developer on their complex types, it turned out that their actual program didn't need so much complexity. Protocols with associated types should be considered an advanced tool; don't reach for them unless you really need them. See [Beyond Crusty](https://www.dotconferences.com/2016/01/rob-napier-beyond-crusty-real-world-protocols) for more on that.*

This doesn't work because it violates your `where` clause:

```
func feed<T:Animal>(to:T) where Self == T.FoodSource
```

So `Animal.FoodSource` has to match `Self`. Let's look at how you use it:

```
SteakSalad().feed(to: Lion())
```

So `Self` is `SteakSalad` and `Lion.FoodSource` is `Meat`. Those are not equal, so this doesn't apply. What you really mean is this:

```
func feed<T:Animal>(to animal:T) where Self: T.FoodSource
```

But that isn't legal Swift ("error: first type 'T.FoodSource' in conformance requirement does not refer to a generic parameter or associated type"). The problem is that `T.FoodSource` could be anything; it doesn't have to be a protocol. "Self conforms to an arbitrary type" is not meaningful Swift.

We could try to improve this by making `FoodSource` at least conform to `Food`, but it gets even worse:

```
protocol Food {}
protocol Meat: Food {}

protocol Animal {
    associatedtype FoodSource: Food
}
```

And then make Lion eat Meat:

```
class Lion : Animal {
    typealias FoodSource = Meat
```

> MyPlayground.playground:1:15: note: possibly intended match 'Lion.FoodSource' (aka 'Meat') does not conform to 'Food'
>
> typealias FoodSource = Meat

Doesn't Meat conform to Food? Hah, no. This is part of the greater "protocols don't conform to themselves" limitation in Swift. You can't just treat protocols like they have inheritance. Sometimes they do, and sometimes they don't.

What you can do is that that meat can be fed to meat-eaters:

```
protocol Meat {}

extension Meat {
    func feed<T:Animal>(to animal:T) where T.FoodSource == Meat {
        animal.eat(self)
    }
}
```

And Veg can be fed to veg-eaters:

```
protocol Vegetable {}

extension Vegetable {
    func feed<T:Animal>(to animal:T) where T.FoodSource == Vegetable {
        animal.eat(self)
    }
}
```

But there's no way I know of to make this generic over protocols-with-associated-types (PATs). It's just too much for the Swift type system. My recommendation is to get rid of the PAT and just use generics. Most of these problems will go away. Even in a language like Scala that has a more powerful type system and also has associated types, the right answer is usually simpler generics (and often not even that; we often make things generic when there's no need).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Regarding the difference between conformance (i.e. `Self : T.FoodSource`) vs equality (`Self == T.FoodSource`) this is still a source of confusion.  If you look at my example, in the generic function which works, it appears to break this rule.  `ChickenSalad` is accepted as food for both `Rabbit` and `Lion` even though the type does not exactly match `T.FoodSource` for either class.

Comment: Thats because the function doesn't invoke `Self`. So `ChickenSalad` is interpreted as `Meat` or `Vegetable` to make the types work. In principle a similar thing could be done for `Self` (or something like it), but this is beyond the compiler's type engine. There are many things about protocols (especially PATs) where "I can work out on paper how that would work" isn't enough; the complier just can't handle it. Generic functions have always been much more flexible in Swift than generic methods. This has gotten better over time, but it's still true.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Yeah I assumed I was hitting the limits of the type system, but it's helpful to understand exactly what those limits are why.